# Logstash 5.6.2 aborts with "warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS"

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I just downloaded latest versions of ELK 5.6.2 to upgrade so that I can use X-pack 5.6.2. Elasticsearch and kibana started with no issues but Logstash is aborting with the below message.
"warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS"
I tried adding set LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" in setup.bat and also -DLS_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" in jvm.options file. Both doesn't seem to work . 
I don't see any log file being generated too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is on windows machine and I am using .zip installations

Comment: Could you post the whole output of when you try to run logstash? I don't think the problem is coming from the warning.

Comment: warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS". This is all I get. Not logs are being generated

Comment: For the logs, have you checked in logstash-5.6.*/logs? What command do you use to launch logstash?

Comment: Yes, the logs folder is not created. The command is \bin\logstatsh.bat -f logstash_config.json I get same warning even when I check the the config with --config.test_and_exit and no logs. I am sure the config file is good as the same file works with logstash-5.5.1

Comment: I don't have any other idea. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: hey, did you find the solution?

Comment: no, we are now at version 6.4

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error log of you.

```
D:\ELK\logstash-7.1.1\bin>logstash.bat -f logstash.conf

warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS= -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true -Djruby.jit.threshold=0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS
```

I see the Comment in “setup.bat”

> JAVA_OPTS is not a built-in JVM mechanism but some people think it is so we warn them that we are not observing the value of %JAVA_OPTS%

I added an environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m`.

logstash started working.

Answer (score 0):

YOURFOLDER\logstash600\bin\setup.bat

find and replace

```
rem JAVA_OPTS is not a built-in JVM mechanism but some people think it is so we
rem warn them that we are not observing the value of %JAVA_OPTS%
rem if not "%JAVA_OPTS%" == "" (
rem   echo|set /p="warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%; "
rem   echo pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS
rem )
set LS_JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
```

** this is NOT 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added an environment variable named LS_JAVA_OPTS and that did not help.
Then I renamed (which is practically removed) JAVA_OPTS environment variable, after which logstash started working. Its a bug in logstash.